# How I can sort an ArrayList of int arrays?

Tags: arraylist, comparator

I have this code. I'm dealing with the N-Queen problem.

The problem is when I wanna show results by screen, the arrays are not ordered. But in this code I can't order them using Comparator. It's very strange because in other Class it works perfectly using Comparator, but here it doesn't work. Hope anyone could help me. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*;

public class NReinas {

public static void resolverReinas(int n){

    String[][] tablero;

    tablero = generarTablero(n);
    ubicarReina(tablero, 0, n);
}

public static void ubicarReina(String[][] tablero, int etapa, int n){

   ArrayList <int[]> resultados = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++){
        if(isValido(tablero, i, etapa)){
            tablero[i][etapa] = "R";


            if(etapa < tablero.length - 1){
                ubicarReina(tablero, etapa + 1, n); //Recursividad
            }else {
                resultados.add(devolverSolucion(tablero, n));
            }
            tablero[i][etapa] = " "; //Backtracking: vaciamos el tablero
        }
    }

    //The ArrayList I want to order by int arrays
    for (int[] r : resultados) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
    }


}

public static boolean isValido(String[][] tablero, int i, int etapa){
    for(int x = 0; x < etapa; x++){
        if(tablero[i][x].equals("R")){
            return false;
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < tablero.length && (i-j) >= 0 && (etapa-j) >=0; j++){
        if(tablero[i - j][etapa - j].equals("R")){
            return false;
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < tablero.length && (i + j) < tablero.length && etapa - j >= 0; j++){
        if(tablero[i + j][etapa - j].equals("R")){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public static String[][] generarTablero(int length){
    String[][]res = new String[length][length];
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
            res[i][j] = " ";
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public static int[] devolverSolucion(String[][] tablero, int n){

    int[] solucion = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tablero.length; j++) {

            if(tablero[i][j] == "R"){
                solucion[i] = j;
            }
        }

    }
    return solucion;
}
```

}

Comment: There is no sort operation nor comparator shown in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Integer instead of int and save array values on List instead, so you can use sort them

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(solucion);
Collections.sort(list);
```

If you insist in using and array you can reconverti the list to an array

```
(Integer[]) list.toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to order values into array, but arrays into ArrayList.

Comment: The contract of `toArray()` (without parameters) is to return an object of type `Object[]`. Casting it to `Integer[]` on a list wrapping an `Integer[]` via `Arrays.asList(…)` happens to work due to a bug in some implementations. Starting with Java 9, this has been fixed and `(Integer[]) list.toArray()` will fail with a `ClassCastException`, as with every other collection.